# NSFetchedResultsController with NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

This is my code:

```
// Create fetch request
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

// Create a sort descriptor for the request
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"stringSortedGroupByFirstInitial" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];


// Use the sectionIdentifier property to group into sections.
 NSFetchedResultsController * fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"stringGroupByFirstInitial" cacheName:nil];


NSError *error;
BOOL failed = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

this working well, but when in the DB I insert this `string` **šić** the boolean `failed` return `YES`

Anyone an idea??

Thanks

Comment: The result of `performFetch` will be YES if the fetch was successful.

Comment: Check the [errors handling guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) to get a better understanding of how it is organized. In this situation you have two results to analyze: the returned boolean value and the value of `error`.